# Extending Devise's SessionsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, rubygems

I am trying to add a before_destroy filter to Devise's SessionsController.

Here is what I have attempted:

I created a module containing the before_destroy filter and another module with the method that I wanted it to call.

```
module UserTracker

  prepend_before_filter :stop_tracking, :only => [:destroy]

  module TrackerStopper
    def stop_tracking
      # Do stuff
    end
  end

  include TrackerStopper
end
```

And then I tried to extend the SessionsController with the UserTracker module.

```
Devise::SessionsController.extend UserTracker
```

This was not working, because devise was not loaded when my module was loaded. This resulted in the error below:

```
uninitialized constant Devise::SessionsController (NameError)
```

Basically, I would like to run a method each time a session gets destroyed, without overwriting the entire SessionsController, but I can't figure out a way to mix it in.

Thanks!

UPDATE 1: I gave up on building a separate gem, here is the code I have attempted in my application.

***UserTrackersController.rb***

```
class  UserTrackersController < Devise::SessionsController
  prepend_before_filter :stop_tracking, :only => [:destroy]

  def stop_tracking
    current_user.update_attributes(:current_sign_in_ip => nil)
  end
end
```

***routes.rb***

```
#--
# Devise
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => 'user_trackers'}
```

The problem now is that if I try to log in (or log out in this case), I get the following error:

```
Template is missing

Missing template user_trackers/new with {:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder, :rhtml, :rxml], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]} in view paths "/net/user10/ardavis2/rubydev/spacecamp/app/views", "/net/user10/ardavis2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@spacecamp/gems/devise-1.3.4/app/views"
```

I don't want my new UserTrackersController to do anything except add some small code to the existing Sessions controller. So I still need devise to function as it did before.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Why don't you really extend SessionsController?

E.g.

```
class MySessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  # my changes
end
```

And in the routing config, you can tell devise_for which SessionsController to use:

```
devise_for :controllers => { :sessions => "my_sessions" }
```

Edit: you can generate devise views by invoking:

```
rails g devise:views <scope>
```

This will generate `app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb` which is the only view you need for this to work. Just copy it to `app/views/my_sessions/new.html.erb` and it will work.

Comment: I never really thought of that. I'm still learning :) I'll give that a shot when I get to work tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: How would I move this into it's own Gem though? I'm still getting the uninitialized constant Devise::SessionsController (NameError)

Comment: I have done everything you mentioned, however it's not working. I also attempted to have 'devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => 'user_trackers'}' and that did the desired actions I had in my custom controller, but when I tried to log out, it was was looking for the user_trackers#new, and not the original sessions new... I want devise to use the same controller, just with some extra code..

Comment: how did you set up devise, is it in your gemfile? I just tested my solution, and it works perfecly. If you subclass Devise::SessionsController, you can override just the parts you want. It's true that MySessionController#new will be called, but unless you redefine it (which doesn't want, you just need a before_filter), Devise::SessionsController#new will be called.

Comment: Devise's guide tells you to use `devise_for` in the routes, which is defined [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb). It also gives a shadow [`app`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/tree/master/app) directory, which can be overridden file-for-file by your own app directory.